# How to validate that a mod uninstalled cleanly?

Tags: starbound

Last night, one of my friends convinced me to join his server. However, to do so without crashing, I had to install a certain mod (Avali, I think it's called), which he ensured me was nothing more than a race mod. The installation was performed by subscribing to the mod on Steam.

Well, that ended up not being true. After exploring for a while, I picked up some item that wasn't part of Vanilla Starbound and my character instantly learned a bunch of non-vanilla recipes. This was undesirable. I cleaned out my inventory and unsubscribed from the mod in steam afterwards.

My question is this: how can I be certain that my Starbound installation is clean? I want no traces of the mod, in case that would cause incompatibility issues on other multiplayer servers. Does unsubscribing from the mod remove the blueprints from my character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsubscribing from mods will remove most traces of them. The only issues that may occur is that sometimes you will get invisible blocks caused by removing the mod that the blocks originally came from (such as an impassable doorway where a door from a mod was). Also, upon reinstalling a race mod, any characters that you have of that race will reappear in your character select. To answer your question specifically, if you unsubscribe from a mod, any blueprints from it will be removed, as the game no longer will have the files for said blueprints.